# 17 and 8 refering to YHVH, His Torah and Good?

Tags: commentaries, gematria-numerology

I found out that the gematria of the word tov is 17, which contracted to 1+7=8. Then I found out that the 17th word of the Torah is Elohim, but also that the words Torah (611=6+1+1=8) and YHVH (26=2+6=8) contract to eight. 
The 17th chapter is the one YHVH and Avram cut out a covenant.

I don't know much about gematria, and it seems one could form all kinds of links and conclusions based on numbers even contradictories ones. But is there a connection between the numbers 17 and 8 and YHVH, His Torah and that which is called Good (Tov?).

Comment: You made yourself a connection.  Are you searching in Holy books some say the same thing? Please explain what you are searching.

Comment: @kouty Presumably he is looking for sources, since he tagged it commentaries. I see nothing difficult about the question. He asked if something is the case. Simple question.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Numbers! Consider registering your account to fully utilize the site's features. Consider also reading this short [Beginners' Guide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775) to Mi Yodeya.

Comment: You are mathematically likely to get spurious correlations when you engage in layers of reductive gematria. Absent something particularly striking (or an authoritative source invoking them), I try to stay away from numerology for that reason - pareidolia.

Comment: Note the chapter numbering is not a Jewish thing so chapter 17 has absolutely zero significance in Judaism

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could think of is a shiur I once read: [link](http://www.berotbatayin.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Iyarlagbomer.pdf)

B’nei Yissascher 
explains that the forty nine days of counting the Omer can be broken down to the 
numerical value of the Hebrew “A good heart” consisting of (
לב
/l
ev
 – 32) and 
טוב(
/
tov 
– 
17). (32+17= 
49) If you count from the firs
t word of the Torah until the word “good” (“
tov
”) in “Hashem saw that it 
was 
good
",
 you will find exactly thirty two words. Together the first thirty two words (
לב
/lev
) and 
the word (
טוב
/
tov
)
 – good 
spell out the expression 
לב טוב
/
lev tov
 – A good heart.
” Hashem 
commanded us to count the numerical value of “A good heart” in preparation for receiving the Torah, 
which embodies the quintessence of “A good heart.” The Torah is the heart of the world. Therefore, it 
has thirty two paths of wisdom. On the first day of Creation, after creating light, the Torah states that 
Hashem saw that the light was good. According to the Midrash, He concealed this light in the Torah. Therefore, the Torah is the essence of good corresponding to the hidden “light that is good.” This explains why Hashem commanded us to count 49 days (32+17) in order to be worthy to receive the Torah.

One thing I liked was founding out that the word Elohim occurs 32 times (the gematria of lev, but this number is also literally written with a Lamed and a Beth in Hebrew) in Bereshit, and the 17th word (refering to that which is "tov") of Bereshit is Elohim.

Answer (score 1):

Maharal speaks about seven being Teva and the number eight being higher (L'Maalah) than Tevah. Perhaps all the things you mentioned hae to do with being higher than Tevah.